# How to use OracleDataReader to retrieve schema data and display it the way i want?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
date          code                name    score         set
09/09/12     967873         Team A         24            1
09/09/12     967873         Team B         22            1
09/09/12     967873         Team A         21            2 
09/09/12     967873         Team B         16            2
02/04/12     965454         Team X         21            1
02/04/12     965454         Team Y         19            1
02/04/12     965454         Team X         21            2
02/04/12     965454         Team Y         19            2
```

you guessed it right! it's a volleyball match! however, I would like my output to be in a single line (I already have retrieved the above table from database). For example:

```
date           code               Teams                 Set-1    Set-2     Set-3
09/09/12      967873             Team A VS.Team B       24-22    21-16       -
and so on....
```

I would like to use vb.net `dataReader` and `html` tables/`dataset` to put the above table in the right format for the user, but having trouble with the `algorithm`.

`**Notice that the game could have a third set as well`
Thanks,

Comment: Could be done in a query. Part to concatenate the two teams and then a pivot. What version of Oracle?

Comment: Tony Hopkinson  Due to the complexity, I will be much easier to do it in vb

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson I agree with Emmanuel. I tried to do a query but it's just tooo complicated. It's not that easy in vb.net either:( 11g Tony

Comment: I didn't want to have a go at writing it anyway, well not unless I was getting paid...

Answer (score 1):

... This could be overkill, but I would do this by just creating a custom object where you can parse out the data the way you need it.
For example:

```
Public Class VolleyBallData

Public Property dbDate As String
Public Property dbCode As String

Private _Teams(2) As String
Public WriteOnly Property dbTeams As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Teams = Value.Split({" VS."}, StringSplitOptions.None)    
    End Set
End Property

Private _Set1(2) As String
Public WriteOnly Property dbSet1 As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Set1 = Value.Split({"-"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    End Set
End Property

...
```

Then, you could just create an output function from your custom object that outputs the data in exactly the way you need it into, say, a `List(of DataRow)`, given that you know that each first element in each array is Team 1's data and each second element is Team 2's.
Then just add those rows to your parent datatable.

Or, quite honestly, you could just as easily do this via functions... I just like custom objects for data validation purposes.

Hope this makes sense...